# Sails.js/Waterline raw SQL query reports syntax error when there seems to be no error

Tags: mysql, sails.js, waterline

I have the following query so I can copy some rows into the same table:

```
START TRANSACTION;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS copy AS SELECT * FROM table WHERE table.field= 'foo';
UPDATE copy SET copy.field = REPLACE(copy.field, 'foo', 'bar');
SELECT @id := MAX(table.uid) AS uid FROM table;
UPDATE copy SET copy.uid = (@id:=@id+1);
INSERT INTO table SELECT * FROM copy;
COMMIT;
```

This works perfectly in MySQL workbench. I then ran the query through Sails.js (using the sails-mysql adapter) but I get the error:

```
{ Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS copy AS SELECT * FROM table WH' at line 1
```

I've logged the query to the console and it looks fine. Why would this happen?

Here's the sails code:

```
  copyTo: function (req, res) {
    var from = req.param('from', '');
    var to = req.param('to', '');
    if (from === '' || to === '') {
      res.send('from and to are required');
    }

    var query = 'START TRANSACTION; CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS copy AS SELECT * FROM table WHERE table.field = \'' + from + '\'; UPDATE copy SET copy.field = REPLACE(copy.field, \'' + from + '\', \'' + to + '\'); SELECT @id := MAX(table.uid) AS uid FROM table; UPDATE copy SET copy.uid = (@id:=@id+1); INSERT INTO table SELECT * FROM copy; COMMIT;';

    Model.query( query, function (err, items) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.send(400);
      } else {
        res.send('ok');
      }
    });
  },
```

The result is essentially a copy of the temporary table reinserted into the original table, with the field property changed

Comment: Can you post your Sails.js code and the logged query result?

Comment: @riza added the code

Comment: [mysql-doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/stored-programs-defining.html), try wrapping the query in something like `DELIMITER + \n {your-sql-here} \n +`

Comment: @birdspider didn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just making a stored procedure and calling it from sails

Answer (score -1):

Sail only work for one statement 
var query = 'START TRANSACTION';
Model.query( query, function (err, items) {
     ...
    });

better use asyn.waterfall for others statement query